# How does zombie spawning in Die2Nite work?

Tags: die2nite

What determines the number of zombies that will be in a zone in the world beyond?

Does killing a zombie while you are in the World Beyond mean that zone will have fewer zombies the next day as well?  Does it basically go through and add a random number of zombies to each zone, and all the ones currently there remain?

Also, does killing a zombie in the World Beyond have any impact on the size of the nightly attack, either on that day or on subsequent days?  Is there any correlation between the size of the nightly attack and the number of zombies in zones in the World Beyond?  Sorry, that's a lot of questions, but I'm sure someone can answer them all.

Comment: I've been wondering these things too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how it appears to work

1. Start by spawning zombies at buildings (day 1)
2. For every night, for every tile:

   - For every neighboring tile with zombies, there's a chance of one more zombie spawning
   - For every two zombies killed in this tile, there's a chance of another one dying by despair.
3. If the total number of zombies drops below 2 × map side × day number, spawn more zombies. (A 12×12 map has side 12.)

We're testing a [spreadsheet](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/Die2Nite%20Zombie%20Predictor.pdf) ([live link](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AvvihYwat4zDdC0yc3BPU3NRbEczX0tWWkt5cWc0YlE&hl=en&output=html)) that puts these rules in practice in [Itching Plantation of Shadows.](http://die2nite.hoah.org/sEt) Time will tell.

Comment: Credits to desolation for this info.

Comment: Wow, very interesting.  So you could theoretically clear an area and it would take a while to fill back in.  Do you know anything about the other half of the question, does this have any impact on the size of the nightly attack?

Comment: 2 × map side × day number that means 24 * 666 = 32K. but bwarner states that the 666day event did not show sky rocketing zombies outside. so what excactly happens in step 3?

Comment: @Andy Zombies would have skyrocketed as the game proceeded to day 667. It didn't, however.

Comment: i see, it took the previous day as whatever it was and not 665. fair enough. i see it very hard to get resources in the later days.

Answer (score 6):

In the forums of the German version there is a post by an administrator that states that the amount of zombies you kill during the day does **not** reduce the number of zombies in the nightly attack. I would assume that it works the same in the English version.

Comment: This makes sense based on the day 666 event, where the number of zombies outside did not increase but the nightly attack skyrocketed.