# Preemptive zombie massacre, good idea?

Tags: die2nite

We know that above a certain total amount of zombies [the only places where zombies spawn is in tiles with neighboring zombies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11937/does-killing-zombies-reduce-their-numbers-on-subsequent-days/11976#11976).

Would it be a good idea to start killing zombies strategically from the start, to try to keep some parts of the map zombie-free? Has anybody tried something like that before? It should also reduce the number of tiles with many zombies on them, reducing the chance of people getting stuck outside.

I'm mainly wondering if it is even possible with the mostly crappy weapons you have in the beginning, and if the efforts would pay off. If I want to try it I'll have to convince my next town that it is a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible or feasible to do so from the beginning, or at all until you get plumbing up.

- You need to find the weapons in the first place! Punching zombies costs AP and only has a slim chance of success.
- Without a watch tower you have no other way of finding out about zombies other than bumping into them, AFAIK.
- Non-water-based weapons break easily and are expensive to repair; water weapons are just too costly before plumbing, not to forget water balloons are strictly throwaway!

Comment: That is what I feared, that the weapons are too inefficient to do that. I'm still thinking that it might be useful on a small scale, to just try to limit zombie expansion a bit.

Comment: @Fabian In practice you'll need to spare them for rescue missions (if somebody is stuck in a tile with 5 zombies, say, you can send two people for rescue, or you can send one person with a weapon or two.)