# How does Zombie Spawning work in Die2Nite?

Tags: die2nite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does zombie spawning in Die2Nite work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11937/how-does-zombie-spawning-in-die2nite-work)

How does zombie spawning work? Do zombies spawn off of other zombies? Any idea what the formula is? If I clear out a whole corner of zombies, will zombies spawn from the edge of the map?

Comment: It feels very awkward to close a general zombie spawning algorithm question as a duplicate of a question that asks for a specific component of said algorithm, even if [has the answer you need](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11937/does-killing-zombies-reduce-their-numbers-on-subsequent-days/11976#11976). Since this is the reverse situation, I think a merging in order, so [I've called this into discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/merging-zombies-into-a-giant-robot-zombie-or-maybe-just-a-more-comprehensive-q).

Comment: Well, as per the discussion over there, and since the answer there did already answer your question, we've decided to just close in this direction after a sufficient edit to the original question. This way, it is, among other things, reversible. But the answer you're looking for should be right there. ♪