# Anyway to reduce attack at night by killing zombies?

Tags: die2nite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does zombie spawning in Die2Nite work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11937/how-does-zombie-spawning-in-die2nite-work)

Does killing zombies in the world reduce that day's attack?

Just wondering if we can't get enough things built for defense if we should walk outside and do a wholesale slaughter of some nearby zombies.

Comment: The possible duplicate sited doesn't really address my question, if killing zombies in the world reduces the nightly attack

Comment: "Also, does killing a zombie in the World Beyond have any impact on the size of the nightly attack, either on that day or on subsequent days?" is part of the question body, and Fabian's answer also explicitly states that it doesn't affect it. It probably helps to note that the original title of the question was "Does killing zombies reduce their numbers on subsequent days?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, killing zombies outside the town has no effect on the nightly zombie attack.

However, killing zombies in a zone has an impact on how many zombies will be in that zone(and neighbouring zones) tomorrow.