# How do you play as a scout?

Tags: die2nite

I know that scouts should locate as many buildings as possible on the first few days. But, does that mean that there will be no point in living or surviving after locating most of the buildings?

How am I able to get back to town if i need to travel far far away from town without using drugs and hero actions?

Answer (score 2):

Die2Nite is a game of teamwork so you're not useless ever, even if you don't have hero actions. That said, the scout abilities are definitely more valuable during the early game.

You benefit from being able to travel through zones unseen (by zombies) and you're able to see zombie counts in adjacent zones. These things are critical for finding buildings and leading other members around before the watchtower is upgraded to level 2 or 3 (it'll detect zombie counts on the map after that).

In my experience, a good town requires a certain number of players who do not go out into the world and just spend points on construction after a certain point. You may be a perfect candidate if you've already make your early game impact as a scout.

If you are still insistent on leaving the town, you can still move unrestricted on the map. Combine that with a powerful weapon and you can make a nice dent in an area of heavy zombie infestation. Considering that [zombie counts are highly dependent](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11937/how-does-zombie-spawning-in-die2nite-work) on the zombies in the area and zombies killed, that kind of thing makes a difference in how the zombie population grows.

As for traveling, you're restricted by AP just like everyone else. There's no special  trick for traveling long distances if you're not a hero (and if you are, use Hero Return) other than to make sure you don't waste your AP when you're in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are a meta-coalition scout or scouting in an organized town, they should be able to give you good tips and pointers and plainly just be able to make use of the(ir) scouts in a good way. I do usually find some buildings the first days but after that just wait and scavenge/build until we have the Watchtower upgraded to lvl 3.

Then I set out with most of my Hero Powers intact and plenty of boosters to find buildings beyond the Watchtower range usually going by zed numbers on the edges of the visible portion of the map.